# Tensorflow compute_gradients and apply_gradients running out of memory

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have the following lines as part of a program:

```
tensor_gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as session:
    for step in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(train_batch_size)
        feed = {input_x: batch[0], input_y: batch[1]}
        gradients = session.run([tensor_gradients], feed)[0]
        for i in range(len(gradients)):
            gradients[i] = (gradients[i][0], tensor_gradients[i][1])
        ... computation on gradients ...
        training_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients)
        training = session.run([training_step], feed)
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I want to modify the gradients using numpy. The above code runs out of memory around step 800. However, if you replace the optimizer.apply_gradients step by tensor_gradients, then the code does not run out of memory.

```
        training_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(tensor_gradients)
```

Any ideas at what might be happening? The rest of the code remains the same except for the line above. Is it possible that the numpy arrays in gradients is not being garbage collected because they are being passed into the apply_gradients step? I have no idea where the memory leak could be or if I'm inadvertently adding to the tensorflow graph by passing modified gradients (in numpy array form) back into apply_gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas at what might be happening?

OOM happens because you're constructing the graph inside the loop: This builds a graph with 20,000x nodes, and running it may need more memory than you have.

Move all TF operations that build the graph outside the loop, *i.e.* everything except `feed_dict` construction and `sess.run` calls.

---

**Reply to comments**

> Apply gradients builds the graph?

Yes, if you look in the docs:

```
Returns:
  An `Operation` that applies the specified gradients. If `global_step`
  was not None, that operation also increments `global_step`.
```

Comment: Apply gradients builds the graph? I thought it applies a new set of gradients to an already built graph. How do you recommend doing this then? I can't move this outside the look because I need to pass in modified gradients.

Comment: Also I don't understand why the graph is being build by apply_gradients only when gradients is passed in and *not* when tensor_gradients is passed into the method.

Comment: MaxB but this still doesn't answer the question why apply_gradients on tensor_gradients does *not* run out of memory. Here, apply_gradients is still in the loop.

Comment: But thanks, though, I'll try moving the operation outside and only call session.run from inside the loop.